# VS 2010 not responding once i open my project ..exception (0x76a0b9bc in devenv.exe)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

when i start visual studio 2010 c# .. and open my application i got this. it stopped responding and gives me that message in the picture once my application is opened but other application works fine.

[image]

then i debug visual studio 2010 .. and i got the exception

Unhandled exception at 0x76a0b9bc in devenv.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352.
[image]

EDIT: i tried to open the .exe file in project folder in debug folder and i got this.

[image]

how to fix that ? what should i do ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've figured out what happened .. my form got 3 usercontrol that i made before.. one of those usercontrol has a customized progressBar which is a library .. for some reason that library stopped working .. so i removed it .. then added again from that usercontrol .. then the application worked.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is vulnerable to certain exceptions that are raised in design mode.  Hard to categorize them, it is an immediate crash to the desktop.  The exception code says as much, 0xe0434352 is a low-level managed code exception.  You'd normally work around it by checking-in an earlier revision of your control and pay extra attention to code that needs to be disabled at design time by checking the DesignMode property.  Your screenshot shows as much, seems like the control is actively displaying runtime info while in design mode.  Risky.

If you want to debug it then you can by starting another instance of Visual Studio and use Tools + Attach to Process to attach to the first one (devenv.exe).  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown boxes for CLR exceptions and Win32 exceptions.  Switch back to the first instance and load your project.

Comment: i've edited the question i got a more clear exception but still don't know what to do !

Comment: That's just a 'file not found' exception.  I don't know where it is either, use Fuslogvw.exe to find out where it looked for the assembly.  And yes, make sure it doesn't try to use that assembly in design mode, there are very few odds that it will find the assembly then unless you put it in the GAC or VS' PublicAssemblies folder.